# Show personal profile in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is the model class that represent the properties of a user profile.

```
public class Profile
{

    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

When users create their profile, their profiles are saved in the database. When they log in using their email and password I want to show them their personal profile only. How can I do this?
I am a beginner in mvc..help me explaining detail please..

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a Profile Controller and put GetProfile as method. getProfile will load all user's data and show them to customer.

```
Public Class Profile : Controller
{
    pubmlic ActionResult GetProfile()
    {
        // get user id in session for instance, or somewhere else, 
        // here I put 5 for the example but it must be dynamic
        int userId = 5;

        // retrieve info and put it in model variable
        Profile userprofil = GetUser(userId);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Where `GetUser(userId)` is the entry point to get the user details, for instance

```
public static Class MyDataAccessLayerForUser
{
    public static Profile GetUser(userId)
    {
        string SQL = "SELECT * from database WHERE user = @user";
        // add @user parameter
        // perform the query
        ...
        Profile data = userReadOnDB;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Then, you have to create the View that shown all elements to user, so in Views/Profile, create a view (.cshtml) named `GetProfile?cshtml` and you just have to use the model that you retrieved in the controller as that:

```
@model YourProjectNamespaceToTheProfileObject.Profile 

@Html.Display(m => m.UserName)
@Html.Display(m => m.Age)
```

So this is the response to your question, But I have to say that there is authentication that is already made for ASP.NET MVC, (it is called Identity), and I advice you to store the date of birth instead of the age of the user :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer...but here,
GetUserprofilMethodThatYouMade();
i can't understand that.. what is that method??

Comment: @ShibliSadik It is the method that read the user's information from your database... you give one id for instance and you get the Profile object with all data filled into it. You have to make this in a separated class/layer in order to re-use the same method because maybe that Admin can select users and see detailed informations for instance, so for code re use, you need to do this, don't put the data access into the controller!

Comment: @ShibliSadik you're ok?